# Working in Emulator getSupportedFocusModes() is null

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-camera

Android 2.3.3 Emulator doesn't recognize focus modes in camera.

```
public class LayerCounterActivity extends Activity {

    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if (checkCameraHardware(getBaseContext())){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Camera OK!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            mCamera=getCameraInstance();

            if (mCamera==null){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Camera not ready!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

                List<String> focusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
```

Why `focusModes` is `null`? When I start the application on a real device, everything works, but Emulator throws null pointer exception.

Comment: Got `null` for both [`getSupportedFocusModes()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedFocusModes()) and [`getFocusMode()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getFocusMode()) on emulators. This behaviour is contrary to what the official docs said. Have to either **check if value is `null`** or **use `try catch`**. Behaviour reproduced on Android 2.2 / Android 3.2 emulators.

Comment: I submitted a [bug report here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42280).

Comment: Obviously, there is no CTS test for this.  I'd suggest you ask them to create a CTS test which *should* catch this error as hopefully they run CTS on the emulator image.

Comment: Check getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.camera.autofocus") whether it has that feature or not